# Upload .tif to GeoServer via Node.js

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff, node-js

How do I upload a .tif file to my running GeoServer via Node.js? 
I'd like to upload a GeoTIFF to provide it as a WMS by the GeoServer.

The GeoServer is responding with a 405, which I think is right (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/coveragestores.html#workspaces-ws-coveragestores-cs-file-extension). Unfortunately, I can't find the file on the GeoServer.

This is my code:

```
// GeoServer upload

    var http = require('http'); 
    var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer('admin' + ':' + 'geoserver').toString('base64');
    //build the object to post
    var post_data = (path.join(paperpath, paperid, "geotiff", req.files["otherfiles"][fileno].originalname)); // Path to .tif file

    var s = JSON.stringify(post_data);
    var post_options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '9000',
      path: '/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Geosoftware-2/coveragestores/test/file',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': s.length,
        'Content-Type': 'image/tif',
        'Authorization': auth
      }
    }
      // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      console.log(res.statusCode);

      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('Success! ' + chunk);
      });
    });
    // post the data
    post_req.write(s);
    post_req.end();
```

Comment: You should just be able to build a `http.request`, put the data in (per the REST API - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/), and call `write()` and `end()` on the request. What have you tried, and what were the results? Can you show a minimal, complete example?

Comment: I edited my post so you can see the code

Comment: @Felix - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jotamon Unfortunately not...